# SQL Trigger is trying to insert a null value but my C# code is passing int 300?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, triggers

I need a little heads up on the mistake I have made on this trigger.  I am using a LINQ to SQL data layer in my asp.net/c# application which inserts data into the database fine before I added this trigger.

I know that the values being passed down into the data layer are perfectly valid as I have checked them in the debugger also.

I am trying to evaluate if an expense for mileage exceeds an annual (uk tax year) limit of 10,000 and split it accordingly for different rates of the claim.

Here is my trigger

```
    USE [Horizon]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trER_InsteadOf_Insert]    Script Date: 07/22/2011 12:21:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Matthew Arnold
-- Create date: 19/07/2011
-- Description: Validate Expense Row for Allowed Mileage
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trER_InsteadOf_Insert] 
   ON  [dbo].[ExpenseRow] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @WorkerID varchar(20);
    DECLARE @ExpenseID int;
    DECLARE @Mileage int;
    DECLARE @Miles int;
    DECLARE @TotalMiles int;
    DECLARE @MilesOver10k int;
    DECLARE @MilesUnder10k int;
    DECLARE @Amount decimal (7, 2);
    DECLARE @AmountOver decimal(7, 2);
    DECLARE @ClaimedDate datetime;
    DECLARE @HighRateMileage decimal (7, 2);
    DECLARE @LowRateMileage decimal (7, 2);

    --Get current mileage and additional miles to work out threshold for worker expense
    SET @ExpenseID = (SELECT Expense_ID FROM inserted)
    SET @WorkerID = (SELECT Worker_ID FROM Expense WHERE Expense_ID = @ExpenseID)
    SET @Mileage = (SELECT Mileage FROM WorkerSettings WHERE Worker_ID = @WorkerID)
    SET @Miles = (SELECT Mileage FROM inserted)
    SET @ClaimedDate = (SELECT ExpenseDate From inserted)

    SET @HighRateMileage = (SELECT Value FROM dbo.SystemSettings WHERE ConfigType_ID = 1 
                            AND @ClaimedDate >=  StartDate
                            AND @ClaimedDate <= EndDate)
    SET @LowRateMileage =  (SELECT Value FROM dbo.SystemSettings WHERE ConfigType_ID = 2
                            AND @ClaimedDate >=  StartDate
                            AND @ClaimedDate <= EndDate)

    SET @TotalMiles = @Mileage + @Miles
    SET @MilesOver10k = @TotalMiles - 10000
    SET @MilesUnder10k = @Miles - @MilesOver10k

            IF (@Mileage < 10000)
                BEGIN
                    IF (@TotalMiles > 10000)
                        BEGIN
                            SET @AmountOver = @MilesOver10k * @LowRateMileage
                            SET @Amount = @MilesUnder10k * @HighRateMileage

                            --Split higher rate and lower rate mileage and insert two expense rows
                            INSERT INTO dbo.ExpenseRow (Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, Mileage,
                                                        ExpenseDate, Description, Amount, Notes, ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, ItemAuthorised, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)

                            SELECT Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, @MilesOver10k, ExpenseDate,
                                                        Description, @AmountOver, 'Calculated at' + ' ' + @LowRateMileage + ' ' + 'pence per mile', 
                                                        ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, 0, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn FROM inserted



                            INSERT INTO dbo.ExpenseRow (Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, Mileage,
                                                        ExpenseDate, Description, Amount, Notes, ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, ItemAuthorised, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)

                            SELECT Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, @MilesUnder10k, ExpenseDate,
                                                        Description, @Amount, 'Calculated at' + ' ' + @HighRateMileage + ' ' + 'pence per mile', 
                                                        ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, 0, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn FROM inserted


                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            --Insert higher rate into the expense row
                            INSERT INTO dbo.ExpenseRow (Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, Mileage,
                                                        ExpenseDate, Description, Amount, Notes, ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, ItemAuthorised, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)

                            SELECT Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, Mileage,ExpenseDate, 
                                                        Description, Amount, 'Calculated at' + ' ' + @HighRateMileage + ' ' + 'pence per mile', 
                                                        ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, 0, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn FROM inserted


                        END

                END


            ELSE 

                    BEGIN
                        SET @AmountOver = @MilesOver10k * @LowRateMileage

                            --Insert lower rate mleage into the expense row
                            INSERT INTO dbo.ExpenseRow (Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, Mileage,
                                                        ExpenseDate, Description, Amount, Notes, ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, ItemAuthorised, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)

                            SELECT Expense_ID, JobNumber, ExpenseType_ID, @Mileage,ExpenseDate, 
                                                        Description, @AmountOver, 'Calculated at' + ' ' + @LowRateMileage + ' ' + 'pence per mile', 
                                                        ClientChargeable,
                                                        VAT_Receipt, 0, AuthBy, 
                                                        CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn FROM inserted


                    END




END
```

Sorry for pasting so much code but I am stumped here but my lack of experience has obviously created this error.

Can you spot my issue as I can't?

Thanks

Comment: It is unable to add the value null into the column mileage as it is a not null field, however the value I am getting is from the temp inserted table passed in by the data layer

Comment: Which field is getting the null?

Comment: Mileage is getting null but I cannot understand why, I debugged it and I know it's going through the pplication ok cuz if I disable the trigger it gets there fine so it is obviously an error in the trigger

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This trigger is totally wrong and needs to be rewritten from scratch. You can NEVER assume you will only have one record in inserted or deleted. Triggers must operate on sets of data not single records.

Comment: @HLGEM: Yes, but the trigger would abort before the insert gets even tried, right? So that's not reason for the null.

Comment: @Klinger, that is irrelevant. What he has is wiorng on all levels. It must be replaced, then he can debug.

Comment: @HLGEM, I can assume in the context this trigger is being used that only record will be inserted because that is how it has been constructed.  I appreciate all feedback, but why is it that you feel I should only use a trigger for a set of data and not single data items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have this line in your trigger:

```
SET @Mileage = (SELECT Mileage FROM WorkerSettings WHERE Worker_ID = @WorkerID)
```

So if `@WorkerID` is `null` or doesn't exist, then `@Mileage` is going to end up being `null` even if you've passed in a proper value for it. This is why the `INSERT` works without the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you how to best develop and debug triggers.

First create temptables for #inserted and/or #deleted'

Then insert mulitple records into the temp tables that would be the data that the trigger inserted and deleted would have. Make sure you cover all the test cases you need. It is critical that you have mulitple records.

Then write your code using #inserted instead of inserted.

Now you can run in steps and check data before the final action. You can also put the whole thing ina transaction that you can automatically rollback until you get the code right.

Finally, I said this in a comment, but never write a trigger assuming only one record at a time will be processed.

Once it's right, change the temp table names to inserted or deleted and add the create trigger code.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have not really done a lot of work around SQL Server and C# in the deail I am currently.  Any advice is appreciated, so thank you!

Comment: I am interested to see how you would write this trigger using all datatypes and tables present above!

Answer (score 1):

Check that Milage in WorkerSettings for the WorkerID associated with the ExpenseID being inserted is not null.